# TYPO3: filter tx_news categories by arguments in the URL

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-10.x

I have a website with TYPO3 v10 and tx_news. I like to know if it is possible to filter categories with arguments in URL something like:

```
 www.mywebsite.com/index.php?id=9&tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=350&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=list&categories=12
```

In this example the link will lead to a page where all news items belong to category id=12.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible by adding the parameter in a form that its handed over to the plugins extbase controller. For tx_news the parameter you ask for looks like:

```
&tx_news_pi1[overwriteDemand][categories]=12
```

You can even make the parameters shorter and more readable by using RouteEhancers in your site: https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/8.5/en-us/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html